Why does pytorch-lightning run so much slower after upgrading？
Before the upgrade, I was using PyTorch Lightning version 0.7.6 and Python version 3.7. After the upgrade, PyTorch Lightning was updated to 2.2.1, and Python was upgraded to 3.8. Although my PyTorch version is also CUDA-based, the runtime of my program has significantly increased after the upgrade, from 30 minutes per epoch to two and a half hours per epoch. I want to take advantage of the new framework's features, but I'm not sure what is causing this issue.
torch.set_float32_matmul_precision('high')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--exp_dir', default='exp/tmp', help='Full path to save best validation model')
parser.add_argument('--pretrain', type=ast.literal_eval, required=True, help='whether to pretrain the stage 1 model')



def main(conf):
    conf['masknet'].update({'n_src': conf['data']['n_src']})
    model, optimizer = make_model_and_optimizer(conf)
    exp_dir = conf['main_args']['exp_dir']

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(exp_dir, 'precheckpoints/')):
        all_ckpt = os.listdir(os.path.join(exp_dir, 'precheckpoints/'))
        all_ckpt = [(ckpt, int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, ckpt)))) for ckpt in all_ckpt]
        all_ckpt.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        best_model_path = os.path.join(exp_dir, 'precheckpoints', all_ckpt[-1][0])
        checkpoint = torch.load(best_model_path, map_location='cpu')
        orig = checkpoint['state_dict']
        model_statedict = model.state_dict()
        for k in orig.keys():
            model_statedict[k[6:]] = orig[k]
        model.load_state_dict(model_statedict, strict=False)
        for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
            param_group['lr'] = conf['optim']['lr']

    train_loader, val_loader = make_dataloaders(**conf['data'], **conf['training'], channels=slice(0, 4))

    # Define scheduler
    scheduler = None
    if conf['training']['half_lr']:
        scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer=optimizer, factor=0.5,  # 实现动态学习率
                                      patience=5)

    os.makedirs(exp_dir, exist_ok=True)
    conf_path = os.path.join(exp_dir, 'conf.yml')
    with open(conf_path, 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.safe_dump(conf, outfile)

    loss_func = BFLoss()
    system = BeamTasNetSystem(pretrain=conf['main_args']['pretrain'], new_lr=conf['optim']['lr'],
                              model=model, loss_func=loss_func, optimizer=optimizer,
                              train_loader=train_loader, val_loader=val_loader,
                              scheduler=scheduler,config=conf)

    checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        dirpath=os.path.join(exp_dir, 'checkpoints/'),
        monitor='val_loss',
        mode='min',
        save_top_k=-1,
        verbose=1
    )

    if conf['training']['early_stop']:
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=2)

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)

    logger = TensorBoardLogger(exp_dir, name="my_model")

    best_model_path = None
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(exp_dir, 'checkpoints/')):
        all_ckpt = os.listdir(os.path.join(exp_dir, 'checkpoints/'))
        all_ckpt = [(ckpt, int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, ckpt)))) for ckpt in all_ckpt if
                    'ckpt' in ckpt and 'init' not in ckpt]
        if len(all_ckpt) > 0:
            all_ckpt.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
            best_model_path = os.path.join(exp_dir, 'checkpoints', all_ckpt[-1][0])
    print("resume from {}".format(best_model_path))

    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=conf['training']['epochs'],
                         enable_checkpointing=True,
                         callbacks=[LearningRateMonitor(), checkpoint_callback],
                         default_root_dir=exp_dir,
                         devices=1 if torch.cuda.is_available() else 0,
                         strategy='auto',
                         accelerator='gpu',
                         gradient_clip_val=5.,
                         logger=logger,
                         # accumulate_grad_batches=6,
                         precision=32,
                         # limit_train_batches=0.1,
                         # limit_val_batches=0.2,
                         # profiler=profiler,
                         )
    print(trainer.strategy.root_device)  # 输出 'gpu' 或 'cpu'

    trainer.fit(system, ckpt_path=best_model_path)

    best_k = {k: v.item() for k, v in checkpoint.best_k_models.items()}
    with open(os.path.join(exp_dir, "best_k_models.json"), "w") as f:
        json.dump(best_k, f, indent=0)

    best_path = [b for b, v in best_k.items() if v == min(best_k.values())][0]
    state_dict = torch.load(best_path)
    system.load_state_dict(state_dict=state_dict['state_dict'])
    system.cpu()

    to_save = model
    torch.save(to_save, os.path.join(exp_dir, 'best_model.pth'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ensure seed is set only once
    seed_everything(seed=0)

    with open('local/conf.yml') as f:
        def_conf = yaml.safe_load(f)
    parser = prepare_parser_from_dict(def_conf, parser=parser)
    arg_dic, plain_args = parse_args_as_dict(parser, return_plain_args=True)
    print(arg_dic)
    main(arg_dic)

enter image description here
I hope to achieve the same speed with this version of PyTorch Lightning as I did before.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
